# PHP preg_replace, not replacing right value

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

The string I am using as my subject is:

> 'Save 68% on a 4 Day/3 Night vacation at. Only $249!'

I'm using `'.\*(\b((enjoy|save)( up to| an extra)?|starting at|as low  as|just|only)\b ([0-9]{1,3} ?\%|\$[0-9]+(\.[0-9]{2})?)).\*/i'` to try to match a part of the above string a extract it.

I'm using `'$1'` as the replacement, so my full `preg_match` looks like

```
preg_match('.*(\b((enjoy|save)( up to| an extra)?|starting at|as low as|just|only)\b ([0-9]{1,3} ?\%|\$[0-9]+(\.[0-9]{2})?)).*/i', '$1', 'Save 68% on a 4 Day/3 Night vacation at. Only $249!')
```

It should match `'Save 68%'` first but it keeps returning `'Only $249'`.

I've found that if I add a question mark after the first wildcard `'.\*?(\b((enjoy|save)( up to| an extra)?|starting at|as low as|just|only)\b ([0-9]{1,3} ?\%|\$[0-9]+(\.[0-9]{2})?)).\*/i'` it does return `'save 68%'`. Is there another way around this. It seems to have to do with my grouping. As I've found that

```
preg_match('/.*\b(enjoy|save)( up to| an extra)?|starting at|as low as|just|only\b.*/i', '$1', 'Save 68% on a 4 Day/3 Night vacation at. Only $249!')
```

returns `'save'` like it should, but I can't get the same thing to work on the full statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why adding a question mark after the first wildcard works, is that `.*` is *greedy*, and the question mark (`.*?`) makes it *lazy*. A greedy operator will match *as much as possible*, which in your case is the whole line (`.*` says "match anything as many times as possible"). Making it lazy will cause it to match *as little as possible*. Read more about this in the [repetition section](http://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.repetition.php) of the PCRE manual pages.

For your particular problem, what's wrong with using the lazy operator? If it results in what you want, I say go with it.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the \b and .* off the start and end of the regular expression. You won't need those, even with a full body of text. See:

http://rubular.com/r/jYjS5WASTw

Comment: Works fine, but I forgot to mention it need to work with mySQL's PREG_REPLACE function as well, which sadly doesn't have all the capabilities found in the PHP version. That was my fault for forgetting to mention that. But otherwise thanks.